# Which provider should be used for the Java Persistence API (JPA) implemenation

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, implementation

I want to use the Java Persistence API (JPA) for my web application.

There are popular JPA implementations like *Hibernate*, *Toplink* and *EclipseLink*.
What implementation is a good choise and why?

Comment: Your first choice should always be the one that comes bundled with your appserver, as it will be the easiest to work with, IMO

Answer (score 65, accepted):

When the **Java Persistence API (API)** was developed, it became popular very fast. JPA describes the management of relational data in applications using Java.

*JPA (Java Persistence API) is an interface for persistence providers to implement.*

Hibernate is one such implementation of JPA. When you use Hibernate with JPA you are actually using the Hibernate JPA implementation.

JPA typically defines the metadata via annotations in the Java class. Alternatively via XML or a combination of both. A XML configuration overwrites the annotations.

***JPA implementations:***

- **Hibernate**: The most advanced and widely used. Pay attention for the
  classpath because a lot of libraries are used, especially when using
  JBoss. Supports JPA 2.1.
- **Toplink**: Only supports the basic JPA specs. (This was oracle’s free
  version of the JPA implementation)
- **EclipseLink**: Is based on TopLink, and is the intended path forward
  for persistence for Oracle and TopLink. Supports JPA 2.1
- **Apache OpenJPA**: Best documentation but seems very buggy. Open source
  implementation for JPA. Supports JPA 2.0
- **DataNucleus**: Well documented, open source (Apache 2 license), is also a JDO provider. Supports JPA 2.1
- **ObjectDB**: well documented
- **CMobileCom JPA**: light-weight JPA 2.1 implementation for both Java and Android.

***Other approaches are:***

- Plain JDBC
- ORM with Hibernate: Hibernate is now also very supportive for JPA
- iBatis: The project moved to MyBatis ([link](http://mybatis.org))
- JDO

*Motivation for Hibernate as my JPA choice:*

- Mature project:

  - Most advanced
  - Well documented
- Useful Hibernate sub projects

  - Hibernate tools: automatic generation of code and database generation
  - Hibernate validation: bean specification capabilities. Integrates with JPA2
  - Hibernate search: powerful full-text search on domain objects
- Active community

  - Big development community
  - Widely used

Hibernate became an open source implementation of JPA very fast after the final specification was published. It has a rich feature set and generates new features fast, because an open-source development process tend to be faster then a Java community process.

Comment: Toplink [is a very mature ORM product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TopLink) that predates JPA by almost a decade.  Toplink Essentials was the reference implementation for JPA 1.  Toplink and Toplink Essentials are very different products.

Comment: "most advanced" ? lol. I can name many features present in other JPA impls (e.g DataNucleus JPA, EclipseLink) that Hibernate doesn't have. Doesn't mean that Hibernate isn't good at some things, but blanket statements like that are (part of) the reason why questions of this nature don't fit on this site. Here you are answering your own question, so maybe its just a FUDDing exercise against other tools?

Comment: With [67% market share](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-tools-and-technologies-landscape-for-2014/), it means that all the other providers combined are used by less than half of Hibernate users. That tells a lot.

Comment: market share tells you nothing about how good something is. Make your own mind up based on your application and the features you need.

Comment: To make this answer more complete: [CMobileCom JPA](http://cmobilecom.com) is a light weight JPA 2.1 implementation for both Java and Android. About 380K.

Comment: I've been using Hibernate for so long in my projects and have not used any others yet. In Hibernate, I have been facing inconsistency issues when updating data in a table. This happens very often while working with a huge number of threads. How do I overcome this inconsistency? Is any other implementation better in that aspect?

Comment: It's also valuable to mention that ObjectDB outperforms all other JPA implementations by a landslide in terms of performance. Unfortunately you will need to purchase a license if you have > 10 entity classes. See the benchmarks here: https://www.jpab.org/All/All/All.html